# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am trying to add a fragment from an activity using the `add(R.id.containerId, fragment);`. However the log gives the `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id` error.

The fragment layout contains an id in the root element. I know that placing the container id in a child element is supposed to fix things, but this has made no difference for me.

Here is the **root element** in the fragment layout xml file:

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#f2f2f2"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".view.fragment.Fragment">
```

Here is the **onCreate()** method in my activity:

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
currentFragment = R.id.fragment_container;
transaction.commit();
```

Here is the **onCreateView()** method in the fragment:

```
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
```

Here is the entire **activity** code (the naming and ids are different because I changed them in the snippets above, imports statements are also missing for brevity):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private int currentFragmentId;

    private FeedFragment feedFragment = new FeedFragment();
    private EventsFragment eventsFragment = new EventsFragment();
    private SearchFragment searchFragment = new SearchFragment();
    private MoreFragment moreFragment = new MoreFragment();
    // Add other fragments

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.main_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(R.id.fragment_feed_container, feedFragment);
        currentFragmentId = R.id.fragment_feed_container;
        transaction.commit();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_feed:
                // Add the feed fragment
                replaceFragment(feedFragment, currentFragmentId);
                currentFragmentId = R.id.fragment_feed_container;
                return true;

            case R.id.action_events:
                // Add the events fragment
                replaceFragment(eventsFragment, currentFragmentId);
                currentFragmentId = R.id.fragment_events_container;
                return true;

            case R.id.action_search:
                // Add the search fragment
                replaceFragment(searchFragment, currentFragmentId);
                currentFragmentId = R.id.fragment_search_container;
                return true;

            case R.id.action_more:
                // Add the more fragment
                replaceFragment(moreFragment, currentFragmentId);
                currentFragmentId = R.id.fragment_more_container;
                return true;

            default:
                // If we got here, the user's action was not recognized.
                // Invoke the superclass to handle it.
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Replaces the current fragment with a new fragment
     *
     * @param newFragment
     * @param currentFragmentId
     */
    private void replaceFragment(Fragment newFragment, int currentFragmentId) {
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(currentFragmentId, newFragment);
        transaction.commit();
    }
}
```

Here is the **full fragment** class (the naming and ids are different because I changed them in the snippets above, imports statements are also missing for brevity):

```
public class FeedFragment extends Fragment {

    public View mView;

    public FeedFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_feed, container, false);
        return mView;
    }
}
```

Here is the code for the **full fragment_feed.xml** file (the naming and ids are different because I changed them in the snippets above, imports statements are also missing for brevity):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_feed_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#f2f2f2"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".view.fragment.FeedFragment">

    <!-- A CardView that contains a TextView -->
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#fff"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="3dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/top_card_linear_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/card_profile_image_view"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="start" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/card_info_text"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="6"
                    android:gravity="start"
                    tools:text="Julien Durrand invited you" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="end"
                    tools:text="3 months" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/card_main_image_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/top_card_linear_layout"
                android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/card_main_image_view"
                android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="start" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:gravity="start"
                    tools:text="30K" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:gravity="center" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:gravity="center" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:gravity="center" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the **main parts of the logcat stacktrace** (the naming and ids are different because I changed them in the snippets above, imports statements are also missing for brevity):

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.tomfinet.magpie/com.tomfinet.magpie.view.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0c0076 (com.tomfinet.magpie:id/fragment_feed_container) for fragment FeedFragment{c9899d7 #0 id=0x7f0c0076}
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0c0076 (com.tomfinet.magpie:id/fragment_feed_container) for fragment FeedFragment{c9899d7 #0 id=0x7f0c0076}
```

**Stuff that I have checked:**

1. Fragment layout is correct in the onCreateView() method in the fragment.
2. Fragment layout container id in child of the fragment xml file.

**How do I fix this error?**

Thank you.

Comment: put the whole snippet and and full stacktrace

Comment: Which snippet? You want the entire log?

Comment: The container `ViewGroup` is what the `Fragment`s `View` is placed into. It shouldn't be in the `Fragment`'s own layout.

Comment: So where should it be?

Comment: In the `Activity`'s layout, if that's where the `Fragment` is being added.

Comment: @TomFinet yes, how will others provide you the solution without having information about where exactly the error can happen?

Comment: But I want to add it dynamically instead of in the xml directly, as adding the fragment dynamically allows me to replace it later.

Comment: I will add the code for the activity and the code for the fragment.

Comment: Right. You just need the container `ViewGroup` - not the whole `Fragment` layout - in the `Activity`'s layout to transact the `Fragment` into. So put the `fragment_container` `LinearLayout` in the `Activity`'s layout XML.

Comment: Thanks so much that worked perfectly! I want to add other fragments, it seems that when I click the action bar icon for those fragments, the fragments load even though the IDs are in the fragment root elements itself. Does this mean that only the initial fragment id needs to be in the activity that is using it.

Comment: Not really. What's happening is, after you add a `Fragment`, its layout becomes part of the `Activity`'s `View` hierarchy, so the next time you transact a `Fragment` with the ID of a container within a previous `Fragment`, the `FragmentManager` finds that container in the `Activity` as usual, and the new `Fragment` is actually being added inside the previous one. Instead of keeping a `currentFragmentId` like you are, all of your `FragmentTransaction`s should just be using `R.id.fragment_container`. Otherwise, you're just nesting `Fragment`s over and over again.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, it really helps. I am only 15 so this is kind of new to me. Thanks.

Comment: For a 15-year-old you are making fantastic progress, I've seen some of your other questions and they were quite good (ie the questions show a good approach). Keep it up Tom!

Comment: btw Mike, you should summarize your comments as an answer so Tom can accept it as the official answer. Helps otherwise and also gives rep to both of you i think